# Cut/Paste Rows from one sheet to another based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

Following this the code that I have already manipulated from another instructional video. I can't seem to get it to work properly hoping that I can get some help. What I am hoping to accomplish is to review a single column in an Excel file and cut the row in which the requirement is met and paste it to the first open row on another sheet.

```
Sub V_LTC()

Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, LTCtype As String, erow As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
LTCtype = Cells(i, "BX")

If (LTCtype = "UVT") Then                 ''''''''''''''''''''''''
ElseIf (LTCtype = "V2") Then              '
ElseIf (LTCtype = "V2A") Then             'Requirements For Sorting
ElseIf (LTCtype = "RMV2") Then            '
ElseIf (LTCtype = "RMVA") Then            ''''''''''''''''''''''''

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(i, "BX").Select
Selection.Cut
erow = Sheet7.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("V-LTC").Rows(erow)

End If

Next i

delete_blank_rows

End Sub

Sub delete_blank_rows()

Dim row As Long

LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LTC and Transfer").Cells(Rows.Count, 
1).End(xlUp).row

row = 2
For row = row To LastRow
If Cells(row, 1) = "" Then
Cells(row, 1).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: *"I can't seem to get it to work properly"* is not a valid problem description. Does it compile? does it raise a runtime error? at which line? what is the error message? are the results different than expected? how do they? Please provide enough information about your problem.

Comment: I seems to compile but it does not actual do anything. I am not getting any errors or at least I am not getting anymore after modifying some things. The posted code is the most recent version. All the references are accurate the if statement could probably use some work, and I don't think it is correct. I want it to look are the criteria and if it does not meet the first one then I want it to go to the next one. I'm not as well versed in VBA as I was a decade ago so some of the coding is guesses that I am hoping will work out.

Answer (score 0):

The `If` statement is wrong, but also many things could be improved, especially relying on active sheet stuff. I think this is all what you need:

```
Sub V_LTC()
  On Error GoTo Cleanup
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.EnableEvents = False
  Dim i As Long

  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LTC and Transfer")
    For i = .Cells(.Rows.count, "BX").End(xlUp).row To 2 Step -1
        Select Case .Cells(i, "BX").Value2
          Case "UVT", "V2", "V2A", "RMV2", "RMVA"
            .Rows(i).Copy Worksheets("V-LTC").Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            .Rows(i).Delete
        End Select
      Next i
  End With
Cleanup:
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```